# Cannot find module 'mongoose' it is saying that app has crashed before starting

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

Although I have downloaded all the required packages then too it is showing :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLYgW.png)

Tried doing - Installed npm packages of mongodb and dotenv.
Expecting - As you can see I am trying to console.log my connection string, I am not able to do it

Comment: Can you share how exactly you installed these packages?

Comment: You need to run   npm install   in the project folder to install dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if anybody is having the same issue as I am, then first of all see that whether you have installed monogdb in your current directory or not. You can see it via `npm list`. If its there then well and good otherwise install it.

And then you should install `npm install mongoose` inside the directory where you have your API, rather than downloading it globally on your system.

It helped me.